# Forcing Scala's XML library to render "singleton tag" (e.g., <br/>) as such

Tags: html, xml, scala, xml-parsing

If I use the `loadString` method to load HTML containing a `<br/>` tag, Scala's XML lib wants to convert that to the longer, and seemingly less standard `<br></br>` (which unfortunately even seems to *render differently* than the plain-old `<br/>` in some browsers).

I.e., the following...

```
val xml = scala.xml.XML.loadString("<body>Hi<br/>there.</body>")
xml.toString()
```

...yields...

```
<body>Hi<br></br>there.</body>
```

Is there a way to force Scala's XML lib to render the tag as a "singleton"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not so!

```
scala> val xml = scala.xml.XML.loadString("<body>Hi<br/>there.</body>")
xml: scala.xml.Elem = <body>Hi<br/>there.</body>

scala> xml.toString()
res0: String = <body>Hi<br/>there.</body>
```

Of course, you are not using Scala 2.10.0, so you see what you are seeing.

Comment: Then the answer is, "upgrade to Scala 2.10"? :)