# Write non self closing tags XML in Scala

Tags: xml, scala

I have `scala.xml.NodeSeq` val and I need to write it to a file.
I'm using `scala.XML.save` to write the file, but it is generating the XML with self closing tags. I need to write it without doing this.
My code is generating a XML like this

```
<value key="attribute"/>
```

I need this

```
<value key="attribute"></value>
```

I've also tried to use `scala.XML.write` method passing the last parameter as `MinimizeMode.Never`, but it also generated the XML with self closing tags.
Do you know any way to avoid this behavior?

Comment: In XML, there is absolutely no semantic difference between those two cases. Whatever "needs" the latter form should be fixed. Having said that, unless scala.XML.save has a feature which will do this for you, if you insist upon it you're going to have to find another XML serializer which does support that option... or postprocess the output document into the desired form via text manipulation.

Comment: yeah. but the annoying program that reads this XML for some reason just can't read it...

Comment: Replace the annoying program. Seriously. If it can't get this right, it's going to continue to make your life miserable by failing to support other basic XML behaviors.

Comment: I have no choice. The program in question is MySQL Workbench. I have to change every single table in my model. so I've opened the file. read its XML, change it and save again. It just does not read output of the script

Comment: In that case: Find another serializer that can work with your XML model and that has the behavior you want (easy if you're using DOM or SAX, harder if you're using something else), or write one (not recommended; XML serialization has some ugly edge cases, but your data might be simple enough to let you get away with a quick-and-dirty solution), or take the Desperate Perl Hacker approach and postprocess the XML text file.

Comment: Browsers don't like `<script src="foo.js"/>`.  It's no surprise that software continues to make life miserable. Like children, we love them anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue running in a older version of scala. Found the answer here: [Forcing Scala's XML library to render "singleton tag" (e.g., <br/>) as such](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948284/forcing-scalas-xml-library-to-render-singleton-tag-e-g-br-as-such)

Answer (score 4):

Well,

```
scala> val x = <value key="attr"></value>
x: scala.xml.Elem = <value key="attr"></value>

scala> x.min
min   minBy   minimizeEmpty

scala> x.minimizeEmpty
res0: Boolean = false

scala> val x = <value key="attr"/>
x: scala.xml.Elem = <value key="attr"/>

scala> x.minimizeEmpty
res1: Boolean = true

scala> val pw = new java.io.PrintWriter(Console.out)
pw: java.io.PrintWriter = java.io.PrintWriter@2b50150

scala> xml.XML.write(pw, x, "", false, null)

scala> pw.flush
<value key="attr"/>
scala> val x = <value key="attr"></value>
x: scala.xml.Elem = <value key="attr"></value>

scala> xml.XML.write(pw, x, "", false, null) ; pw.flush()
<value key="attr"></value>
scala> val x = <value key="attr"/>
x: scala.xml.Elem = <value key="attr"/>

scala> xml.XML.write(pw, x, "", false, null) ; pw.flush()
<value key="attr"/>
scala> xml.XML.write(pw, x, "", false, null, xml.MinimizeMode.Never) ; pw.flush()
<value key="attr"></value>
```

There are NodeSeq's other than Elem, obviously:

```
scala> val n: NodeSeq = new xml.Unparsed("""<value key="attr"/>""")
n: scala.xml.NodeSeq = <value key="attr"/>

scala> xml.XML.write(pw, n.head, "", false, null, xml.MinimizeMode.Never) ; pw.flush()
<value key="attr"/>
scala>
```

Showing the bug the OP is pointing out:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import xml._
import xml._

scala> val pw = new java.io.PrintWriter(Console.out)
pw: java.io.PrintWriter = java.io.PrintWriter@17d99928

scala> val x = <value key="attr"><value key="another"/></value>
x: scala.xml.Elem = <value key="attr"><value key="another"/></value>

scala> xml.XML.write(pw, x, "", false, null, xml.MinimizeMode.Never) ; pw.flush()
<value key="attr"><value key="another"/></value>
scala>
```

https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/xml/Utility.scala#L237

Edit, showing it fixed in 2.12:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.3 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import xml._
import xml._

scala> val pw = new java.io.PrintWriter(Console.out)
pw: java.io.PrintWriter = java.io.PrintWriter@1a256d80

scala> val x = <value key="attr"><value key="another"/></value>
x: scala.xml.Elem = <value key="attr"><value key="another"/></value>

scala> xml.XML.write(pw, x, "", false, null, xml.MinimizeMode.Never) ; pw.flush()
<value key="attr"><value key="another"></value></value>
scala>
```

https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/commit/b696beaa481a11a5276186b9e2bc2be3cb32a922

Comment: did not work. the problem is with the child elements. the write method calls a serialize method in a Utility class from `scala.XML` package. I've read the code and at some point when writing the children it just ignore the MinimizeMode

Comment: When I was first learning Scala, I had to copy that code to fix a different issue... https://github.com/som-snytt/House-of-Mirrors-Fork/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/xml/XMLFormatter.scala#L288

Comment: I guess you mean here. They take pull requests, but there are other scala xml libs, too. https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/xml/Utility.scala#L237

Answer (score 0):

One remedy is to fix up the XML tree, explicitly setting the `minimizeEmpty` property of each element.

```
  def fixSelfClosing(nodes: Seq[Node], minimize: Set[String]) : Seq[Node] = {    
    nodes.map(n => n match {
      case e: Elem => e.copy(child = fixSelfClosing(e.child, minimize),
        minimizeEmpty = minimize.contains(e.label))
      case _ => n
    })
  }
```

When calling `XML.write` with `MinimizeMode.Default`, transform the root element:

```
  XML.write(pw, fixSelfClosing(Seq(rootElement), minimizedTags)(0),
    xmlDecl = false, doctype = null, 
    minimizeTags = MinimizeMode.Default)
```

where `minimizedTags` is the set of tags that you want to have self-closing. For example, with XHTML:

```
  val minimizedTags = Set("area", "base", "br", "col", "embed", "hr", "img", "input", "link", "meta", "param", "source", "track", "wbr")
```